# Recursive function not terminating even when break condition is met - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, async-await, es6-promise

I'm building a React.JS component which, on button click, fetches a Joke from the `JokeAPI` and narrates it using the Web Synthesis text-to-speech API. I want to stop this narration and fetching of the Joke when the `stop` button is pressed through a global boolean variable. However, the function isn't stopping and keeps executing recursively.

**JokeComponent.js**

```
export default function JokeComponent() {
  const [jokeState, jokeStateSetter] = useState();
  var RUNNING

  const fetchAndNarrate = () => {
    if(RUNNING){
    axios.get("https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any").then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      //the returned joke is twopart ie. with a setup and a delivery
      if (res.data.type === "twopart") {
        jokeStateSetter(res.data.setup);
        //If speech synthesis compatible, narrate
        if ("speechSynthesis" in window) {
          say(res.data.setup).then(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              jokeStateSetter(res.data.delivery);
              if ("speechSynthesis" in window) {
                say(res.data.delivery).then(() => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    fetchAndNarrate();
                  }, 4000);
                });
              }
            }, 2000);
          });
          //If speech synthesis not compatible with browser, just display the joke without narration
        } else {
          setTimeout(() => {
            jokeStateSetter(res.data.delivery);
          }, 4000);
          fetchAndNarrate();
        }
        //the returned joke is in a single sentence
      } else if (res.data.type === "single") {
        jokeStateSetter(res.data.joke);
        //If speech synthesis compatible
        if ("speechSynthesis" in window) {
          say(res.data.joke).then(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              fetchAndNarrate();
            }, 4000);
          });
        }
        //If speech synthesis not compatible with browser, just display the joke without narration
        else {
          setTimeout(() => {
            jokeStateSetter(res.data.delivery);
          }, 4000);
          fetchAndNarrate();
        }
      }
      // //the returned joke is of neither type
      // else {
      //   fetchAndNarrate();
      // }
    });
  } else 
      return
  };

  const say = function (text) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
      utterance.onend = resolve;
      window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>{jokeState}</h4>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          RUNNING = true
          fetchAndNarrate();
        }}>
        Start
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          RUNNING = false
          //window.speechSynthesis.cancel();
        }}>
        Stop
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When the `Start` button is pressed, `RUNNING` is set to `true` and the recursive function `fetchAndNarrate ()` is executed. Inside, I have used `setTimeout` to give a small pause between the joke's setup and delivery and also the next joke. The idea behind having this recursive function is for the jokes to keep going until I press the `stop` button. When it is pressed, I set `RUNNING` to false. `say()` is a function which returns a promise that resolves when the Joke is fully narrated.

**The expected behavior:** On stop, the current joke completes its narration and the function should fail the `if(RUNNING)` condition and return on the next iteration without fetching another joke from the API.

**The observed behavior:** On stop, the current joke completes narration and the function somehow keeps going and fetches another joke on the next iteration despite `RUNNING` being set to `false` *and the function never stops.*

I think I have too many nested promises in that function which is where I could have messed up. I am new to JavaScript and Promises and I'm not sure if having so many nested promises is ideal.

Please help a brother out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined RUNNING as local variable in the function. Define it really as global, like window.RUNNING, then your works.

Answer (score 2):

You could make your code a heck of a lot more readable with async/await and a couple of helper methods. Granted Ive used `fetch` but the same will work with axios. There's no need to make it recursive, a simple `while` loop will do just fine.

```
async function run() {    
    while(running) {
        var res = await fetch("https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any")
        var json = await res.json();
        if(json.type == "twopart") {
            await say(json.setup);
            await delay(1000);
            await say(json.delivery);
        }
        else if(json.type == "single") {
          await say(json.joke)
        }
    }
}
```

Live example:

```js
const say = function(text) {
  out.innerHTML = text
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
    utterance.onend = resolve;
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
  });
};
const delay = t => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t))

const out = document.querySelector("#output");
const stop = document.querySelector("#stop")
stop.addEventListener("click", () => running = false)
let running = true

async function run() {

  while (running) {
    var res = await fetch("https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any")
    var json = await res.json();
    //console.log(json)
    if (json.type == "twopart") {
      await say(json.setup);
      await delay(1000);
      await say(json.delivery);
    } else if (json.type == "single") {
      await say(json.joke)
    }
  }
}

run()
```

```html
<div id="output">

</div>
<button id="stop">
Stop
</button>
```